# How can I derive a non-central chi-square distributed random variable from non-standard normal random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared

Hamilton, on page 101 of his textbook Statistics in Physical Science says that the non-central $\chi^2$ distributed random variable with $k$ degrees of freedom can be though of as the sum of squares of $k$ independent normal random variables $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2), i = 1,...,k$.

Many other sources say that the i.i.d. normal r.v.s must all have unit variance. How do I derive the non-central $\chi^2$ distribution from $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ r.v.s?

Comment: See this: [Non-central Chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution). I guess you are confused between **normal distribution** and **standard normal distribution**. See this also: [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and [Standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution).

Comment: The one place I didn't find. Thanks @NashJ.